# Can I send an NSURLRequest over a socket?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I would like to take an NSURLRequest and turn it into some usable data that is ready to be written to a socket() instead of something like an NSURLConnection.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to do? What's wrong with a NSURLConnection?

Comment: NSURLConnection has some bugs in Lion, specifically around sockets being left open in the "CLOSE_WAIT" state. I would like to drop down to using raw sockets so when there are problem I can actually do something about it.

Answer (score 1):

NO!

You can create a NSMutableURLRequest and provide that request with a HTTPBodyStream then create a NSURLConnection to send the request.

The HTTPBodyStream is an NSInputStream the request will read the body from. You can get it value from user, file or NSData.